# How to convert characters in CCSID 65535

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, odbc, oledb, ibm-midrange

My application is in VB.Net and I'm using the driver of IBM Client Access to access data on our IBM iSeries server.

The problem is that some characters are not translated automatically in CCSID 65535 (i.e. the € character) and the update/insert command fails.

I don't know on which level the problem must be handled. On the ODBC driver ? In the connection string ? Or do we have to create a conversion dll ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: By definition, CCSID 65535 is "binary" data and should not be converted. If you need to pull 'character' values out of it, it is necessary to know what CCSID the data was when it was stored as CCSID 65535. E.g., if it was an ASCII CCSID when itwent in, you have to use the same ASCII CCSID when you try to read it back out. And if it was CCSID 37 (US English) when it went in, it'll only be correct if you read it as CCSID 37. CCSID 65535 is generally a bad idea setting for storing any character data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `BinAsChar=true` set in the Connection String. You might also need to set either `CCSID` or `Host CCSID` to one that's valid for you, the default us 37 which is US/Canada. Here's more info on connection string parameters for DB2:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251805%28BTS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, the BinAsChar box is checked in the ODBC Administrator. Setting CCSID to 1148 (Belgium) on the server indeed solves the problem but they don't want to replace the 65535 CCSID by another one ! I thus have to convert characters in another way ...

Comment: Can you not change the CCSID in the connection string to automatically convert it? I'm not too familiar with this so I don't know if that's an option or not even.

Comment: Actually, iSeries doesn't support double-byte characters and no dataprovider seems to convert them into single-byte characters. The only solution we found so far is to convert characters inside the .Net application.

Comment: Actually, the AS/400 series (including iSeries and later) handles double-byte characters fine. Files can have double-byte mixed with single-byte if necessary. Or one column in a table can be double-byte, and the next column can be single-byte. The issue almost invariably comes down to improper setting of the QCCSID system value together with incorrect table and column definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the DSN using the "iseries Access ODBC Driver" by using the Windows "ODBC Administration" tool.  In the configuration setup, select the conversions tab and check the box "Convert binary data (CCSID 65535) to text.